Tesla Universal Wall Charger - J1772 Adapter not "staying" in wall charger port, coming off CCS plug
I am unable to get the J1772 adapter to "stick" in the inside of the Tesla Universal Wall charger holding port, or release / remove the adapter manually from the CCS Tesla style plug underneath. This is preventing me from using the wall charger to charge my Tesla. Is there a way to get this working properly again?

Some Context:

The Tesla Universal wall charger has a cool functionality that allows you to pull the plug out either by just tugging (which pulls the plug out leaving a Tesla style CCS plug exposed), or by pressing a latch button on top which pulls the plug out with a J1772 adapter "attached" to the CCS plug. If you pull it out this way there doesn't seem to be any way to get the adapter off of the CCS plug manually, other than to stick it back into the side of the wall charger, and after the adapter potion catches, pulling the CCS plug back out without pushing the latch button (leaving the J1772 adapter in the Universal Wall charger port).

Workarounds:

I put the J1772 -> CCS adapter that comes with car so that you can use charge point etc chargers onto the CCS -> J1772 adapter that is stuck and the monster actually plugs in. Not a long term fix however
I heard that you might be able to get it to come off by placing a strong (earth) magnet on the QR code section (which is how the wall charger is supposed to do it) of the J1772 adapter but I don't have one of those, and you'd be unable to store the plug in the wall charger which would be annoying.

